# Push Web Service: Invalid UTF-8 start byte

Tags: java, web-services, soap, utf-8, glassfish

I try to create a Web Service and should receive datas via push. I generated a Web Service with NetBeans from WSDL. Unfortunately I get always in the output:

> Couldn't create SOAP message due to exception: XML reader error:
>   com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0x8b
>   (at char #2, byte #-1) Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException:
>   Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0x8b (at char #2, byte #-1)

If I change the binding type:

```
@BindingType(javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPBinding.SOAP12HTTP_BINDING)
```

I get:

> Unsupported Content-Type: text/html Supported ones are:
>   [application/soap+xml]

So it's a 1.1 SOAP protocol (change to SOAP11HTTP_BINDING).

I use Glassfish 3.1.2.2 and changed already the JVM-Options to:

```
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

and

```
-Dfile.encoding=UTF8
```

but didn't help. UTF16 or UTF-16 throws exceptions.

This is how my pom.xml looks like:

```
...
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsimport</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <wsdlFiles>
                                <wsdlFile>PushService.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                            </wsdlFiles>
                            <staleFile>${project.build.directory}/jaxws/stale/PushService.stale</staleFile>
                        </configuration>
                        <id>wsimport-generate-PushService</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
                        <artifactId>webservices-api</artifactId>
                        <version>1.4</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <configuration>
                    <sourceDestDir>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/jaxws-wsimport</sourceDestDir>
                    <xnocompile>true</xnocompile>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <extension>true</extension>
                    <catalog>${basedir}/src/jax-ws-catalog.xml</catalog>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
...
```

How can I solve this issue?

**Update:**
Reason was that the Service sends the request gzipped. So how can I decompress the gzipped answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently Glassfish doesn't support gzip-decoding yet. So I implented a Filter, which decodes the Input:

```
@WebFilter(filterName = "GZipInputFilter", urlPatterns = {"/*"})
public class GZipInputFilter implements Filter
```